# Application freeze when running long Sql queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf

I have application server that connects to Sql Server database and returns query results to client applications via WCF. Most of code there is like that:

```
using(SqlConnection sqlConnection = GetConnectionProvider().NewConnection())
{
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(data.SelectStoredProcedureName,     sqlConnection);
    sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 600;

  ... add params

    using (SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader())
    {
      ... fill data
    }

    return serializedData;                
}
```

in 99.99% percent of cases it works well but in some rare cases application begins to work very slowly. Average response time is 13 ms. After that freeze response time grows to 300-400 ms. Application begins to use 1 GB of memory and 100% cpu usage.

I'm not sure, but it can be related with running long sql queries. For example: during ordinary work some user runs long time running report. It can cause server freeze.

What can be a reason of that behavior? Any thounghts how I can diagnose that?

Comment: I think you will need to run some tests to see *which* queries are causing your software to be unstable at times and take it from there. Other than that, I think that we can only speculate.

Comment: Another thing you can do is to check for locks on the SQL Server. Sounds like you could be experiencing a lock (maybe caused by a user running a report as you suggested), preventing other queries from accessing the data. You can find some information about investigating locks here: http://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/05/26/locking-in-microsoft-sql-server-part-4-how-to-detect-blocking/

Comment: Problem is that long running query ends, but  my application is still frozen. Question is why? resources are not locked anymore. If I restart app everything works ok.

Comment: can you add some details about your service configuration and how big data has been query or transmitted?